# html output in plsql - date not proper

Tags: html, sql, oracle, to-date

I am trying to extract the below query:

```
select
'<tr><td>'||column1||'</td>',
'<td>'||column2||'</td>',
'<td>'||column3||'</td></tr>'
from table
```

In the above, column3 is a date field. When the output is printed, it is ignoring the time part. For example:

```
If columns 3 output is : 5/25/2011 3:03:17 AM
The above query returns : <tr><td>column1</td><td>column2</td><td>**25-JUN-11**</td></tr>
```

I have tried to_date(column3,'yyyy/mm/dd HH24:MI:SS') and also, the normal query prints the time

```
select
column1,
column2,
column3,
from table
```

columns 3 prints time. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:**
I am using Oracle 10g. I have also tried it in Oracle 9i

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't rely on implicit conversions, use [`TO_CHAR`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions200.htm#i1009324) to display a date [to your liking](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#i34924):

```
select '<tr><td>'||column1||'</td>', 
       '<td>'||column2||'</td>', 
       '<td>'||to_char(column3, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')||'</td></tr>' 
  from table
```

Answer (score 1):

[TO_DATE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm) does exactly what it's supposed to do, format mask supplies it with the format it's primary input is in so it can transform it into a date. The format mask is not used to define output but input. What you need to use instead is [TO_CHAR](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm)

```
TO_CHAR(column3,'yyyy/mm/dd HH24:MI:SS')
```